# Formato de hora com sprintf

Tags: php

Estou com o seguinte problema, estou a trabalhar com horas em php.

Tenho de calcular o intervalo de tempo, entre a hora de inicio e a hora de fim, para tal estou a utilizar o seguinte código.

```
$entrada = $dados[$z]['hora_inicio'];

if($dados[$z]['hora_fim'] != ""){
    $saida   = $dados[$z]['hora_fim'];
}else{
    $saida = date('H:i');
}

$entrada = explode( ':', $entrada );
$saida   = explode( ':', $saida );
$minutos = ( $saida[0] - $entrada[0] ) * 60 + $saida[1] - $entrada[1];


if( $minutos < 0 ) $minutos += 24 * 60;

print sprintf( '%d:%d', $minutos / 60, $minutos % 60 );?>
```

E o formato retornado é `0:0`, mas eu necessito do seguinte formato `00:00`, alguma dica de como eu posso alterar o formato, para que fique 00:00?

Comment: Para corrigir isto bastaria utilizar: `%02d:%02d` ao invés do `%d:%d`.

Comment: muito obrigado, meta como resposta, pois funcionou prefeirtamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta alterar a última linha para o seguinte:

```php
print sprintf( '%02d:%02d', $minutos / 60, $minutos % 60 );
```